# How to prevent excessive host CPU usage when running Ubuntu 17.04 in a VMWare Workstation v.12 VM?

Tags: 14.04, 17.04, vmware

I'm trying to set up Ubuntu 17.04 in a VMWare Workstation VM running on a Win10 laptop.  I've been running Ubuntu 14.04 in a VM on the same system for about a year without any major problems.

Unlike my 14.04 VM, running the 17.04 VM causes excessive (30-50%) CPU activity by VMWare according to the laptop’s Task Manager. When 14.04 is running (by itself), VMWare runs at a few percent according to Task Manager.

I suppose if I could run the Activity Monitor in 17.04 I can try to see what is going on that accounts for the high CPU %, but I haven’t managed to find how to add Activity Monitor (or anything else for that matter) to the Launcher - I only stumbled on how to start Terminal by accident (right-clicking the desktop).

So, how to identify and fix the cause of the high CPU % caused by running the 17.04 VM?

**Update:**  As suggested by @vidarlo, I've run `top` in `Terminal` and is says that the CPU activity is coming approximately 75% from `vmare-conig-t` and 25% from `tee`.  What can I do to fix that?  Please note that thanks to another problen I'm having, I'm unable to access the internet from the VM, so can't download any updates.  Also btw, in case it's relevant, the usual VMWare Tools icons are displayed at the lower RHS of the VM window.

Comment: Run `top` in a terminal to show resource use.